# Hashmap Syntax error on tokens in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using openscript IDE, I am getting an error "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"
my code is

```
import java.util.Map;
public class HTMLObjectMap {

   HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put("test","test");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The statement

```
params.put("test","test");
```

has to be inside a method, which you haven't defined.  I.e.

```
public class HTMLObjectMap {

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public void method()
    {
        params.put("test","test");
    }
}
```

Or, possibly you want an initializer, as in

```
public class HTMLObjectMap {

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    {
        params.put("test","test");
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case since `params` is not static, an initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put initialization code into braces:

```
public class HTMLObjectMap {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    {
        params.put("test","test");
    }
}
```

or if you need it static:

```
public class HTMLObjectMap {
    static HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static
    {
        params.put("test","test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working... I need to make it static, and refer in other class I need to use the

Comment: Thanks its working... I need to make it static, and refer in other class I need to use the  params.put("tag1","link"); params.put("tag2","button");params.put("tag3","radiobutton"); do I need make it static map and use or I need to make clas static

Comment: It was not static in your example, so it was not in mine.  Added example with static map.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make your map private it will not break encapsulation and getter and setter method for accessing & inserting it's value outside.

```
public class HTMLObjectMap {

   private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   {
       // initialize if required  
   }
   public void get(String key){
         params.get(key);
   }
   public String put(String key,String value){
         params.put(key,value);
   }
}
```

Comment: No I am using Hashmap with set values to initalize it. I need to add key and values, which I will be referring later

Comment: Use initializer block or even you can insert in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the class. A java class only have variables and methods. inside class you can declare variables or define methods , whatever else you want do means you have to define methods.

```
public class HTMLObjectMap {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // this is objects method.
    {
        params.put("test","test");
    }
    // this is your own method
    private void method1(){
        params.put("test1","test1");
    }
}
```